# Getting the position of an element inside an Angular Material Dialog Container

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm trying to retrieve an element inside a material dialog container so that I can use it's position.

I am using [Material Angular](https://material.angular.io/components/categories), and specifically the [Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview).

So far I have tried the `getBoundingClientRect()` after getting the element with it's associated id.

Using `document.getElementById(elementId).getBoundingClientRect()` returns `{"x":0,"y":0,"width":0,"height":0,"top":0,"right":0,"bottom":0,"left":0}`

Where `elementId` is the id of the button that is inside the mat-dialog.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that comes across this from my stupidity, the answer is that the element I was looking for was hidden and had no position.

I had two buttons with the same id, and it just got the first one that was in the DOM.

Changing the id of the button fixed that.